# Переклад слова "запоминающийся"

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова, синоніми

Є таке речення, що треба перекласти українською: "Модель имеет *запоминающийся* утонченный внешний вид, гармонично вписывающийся в традиционный дизайн компании Apple". 
 [Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) надає такі відповідники слова *запоминающийся*:

> **Запоминающийся** – (пас. свойств.) запам’ятни́й, запам’ято́вний; (при пас. действ.) запам’ято́вуваний; (неперех. свойств.) пам’ятки́й;
>   (при неперех. действ.) що запам’ятовується.

[Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=8&highlight=on) надає як варіант "заміткий".

Який із варіантів буде доречніше використати в даному контексті?

Comment: Чому б не використати трішки інше слово, наприклад, незабутній?
Одне з значень якого - "Який надовго, глибоко запам'ятався.".
Модель має незабутньо витончений зовнішній вигляд... 
Або ще є слово - ДОСТОПА́М'ЯТНИЙ, приблизно з таким же значенням.

Comment: А особисто я б трішки згладив переклад, і не намагався б перекласти все дослівно. Тому легко можна використати слова  - помітний, яскравий, вражаючий.

Answer (score 1):

Погоджуюся з тим, що тут можна використати слово "[незабутній](http://sum.in.ua/s/nezabutnij)", також можна перекласти дане слово не одним українським, а декількома, наприклад: "Модель має витончений зовнішній вигляд, який надовго закарбується/залишиться у вашій пам'ятій...", або ж "..., який ви не скоро зможете забути" чи "..., який ви надовго запам'ятаєте".

Гадаю, що також хорошими варіантами будуть "дивовижний", "приголомшливий", "яскравий".